# Передача кода клавиши в аргумент функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть код

```
element.keydown(arrowMove(Key.Code));
```

Реализовать хочу в

```
function arrowMove(key)
        {
            if (key == 55)
            {
                //что то делаем
            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
```

Так собственно как передать код клавиши которая будет нажата на элементе.
Пробывал передавть `event` но толку ноль

Comment: А что выводит `event.keyCode`?
Пример реализации функции имеется вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events#getChar).

Comment: не совсем понял вопроса.`function arrowMove(event)
        {
            console.log(event.keyCode);
        }`если вы про это то не чего не выводит в консоль

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, к вопросу ссылку на песочницу со своим кодом (html/js).

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```
element.keydown(function(event){
  arrowMove(event.keyCode);
});
```

или

```
element.keydown(arrowMove);
function arrowMove(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 55) {
    //что-то делаем
  }
}
```

Comment: добавь описание, почему не работает код в вопросе, и чем твой код отличается от кода в вопросе